# php - Getting ready array for using as sitemap (

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel

I want to generate sitemap , so I created array from my database result and convert array to xml , finally I displayed xml file as sitemap.

Here is my code :

Firstly , I fetch my data from database :

```
    $restaurantList = $DoctrineRestaurantRepo->getInformation();
    foreach ($restaurantList as $key => $value)
    {
        $resSlug = $restaurantList[$key]['restaurantSlug'];
        array_push($initialArray,  ["url"=>["loc" => $resSlug , "changefreq" =>"monthly" , "priority"=>"0.6"]]);
    }
```

Here is result :

```
array:102 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "url" => array:3 [▼
      "loc" => "example.com/jack"
      "changefreq" => "monthly"
      "priority" => "0.5"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "url" => array:3 [▼
      "loc" => "example.com/alex"
      "changefreq" => "monthly"
      "priority" => "0.5"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "url" => array:3 [▼
      "loc" => "example.com/anna"
      "changefreq" => "monthly"
      "priority" => "0.5"
    ]
  ]
  .
  .
  .
]
```

Then , I convert it to xml :

```
$xml_template_info = new \SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><urlset></urlset>");

$this->array_to_xml($initialArray,$xml_template_info);
$xml_template_info->asXML(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml") ;

public function array_to_xml(array $arr, \SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        is_array($v)
            ? $this->array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k))
            : $xml->addChild($k, $v);
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

And xml file is look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset><0><url><loc>example.com/jack</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url></0><1><url><loc>example.com/alex</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url></1>....</102></urlset>
```

Finally , I wanted to display xml :

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
readfile(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml");
exit();
```

Actually , I get an error :

[image]

I think my xml file  is wrong , I have two question :

1- I want to remove key from result , so my xml file should be like this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset><url><loc>example.com/jack</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url><url><loc>example.com/alex</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.6</priority></url>....</urlset>
```

How to do this?

2- what the meaning of that error?

Comment: what version of laravel you are using?!

Comment: @ClearBoth I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: why not using https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap instead. Anyway you can find if this answer useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/28608156/3399676